# Higher homotopy of diffeomorphism groups from singularities

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, differential-topology, singularity-theory, transformation-groups

In the case of a genus $g$ surface $\Sigma$, it is well known that $MCG(\Sigma) = \pi_0 \operatorname{Diff}^+(\Sigma)$ is generated by **Dehn twists**, which come from a Kahler degeneration with smooth total space in which $\Sigma$ acquires an $A_1$-singularity. This has a generalization to higher dimension: if $X$ is a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold, with a (framed) Lagrangian sphere $L \subset X$, there is a diffeomorphism which preserves the symplectic form defined on the local model $T^* S^n$ as the time-$\pi$ map of a truncated geodesic flow on the cotangent bundle. Like the surface case, generalized Dehn twists also have a singularity-theory description as the monodromy of a Kahler degeneration with smooth total space where $M$ acquires an $A_1$-singularity (see [Seidel's " A long exact sequence in Floer homology"](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0105186)).

When $n$ is odd, Dehn twists have infinite order in $\pi_0 \operatorname{Symp}(X)$ **and** $\pi_0 \operatorname{Diff}^+(X)$ because of Picard-Lefschetz formula for the action on middle homology. When $n=4$, Dehn twists have order 2 in $\pi_0 \operatorname{Diff}^+(X)$ (here smooth topology and symplectic topology diverge). For $n>4$ even, Dehn twists have finite order in $\pi_0 \operatorname{Diff}^+(X)$ (see Lemma 4.1 in [Exotic Iterated Dehn twists](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.4615.pdf)). We can even bound that order explicitly as follows from the work of [Stevens](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/stevens.pdf) and [Kauffman-Krilov](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0308277.pdf).

The monodromy around a Kahler degeneration to an ADE-singularities are known to yield products of Dehn twists (See [Seidel's "Lagrangian 2-spheres can be symplectically knotted"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9803083.pdf) or [Smith-Thomas-Yau "Symplectic conifold transitions"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0209319.pdf)).

My question is about generalization of that:

1) Are there singularities whose miniversal deformation space is interesting enough so that it yields non-trivial (ideally, infinite order) elements in $\pi_i \operatorname{Diff}^+(X)$ with $i \geq 1$?

2) Is there some kind of generalized "Picard-Lefschetz" formula for the action in that case?

Comment: Presumably you are looking for minversal deformations of dimension $n >1 $ where every fiber but the generic fiber is smooth, which then provide elements in $\pi_{2n-2}$ of the diffeomorphisms of the smooth fiber?

Comment: Do you mean - every fiber except the special fiber? Then yes, the problem is that I want the elements to have infinite order, so the topology of the space of possible deformations should be nontrivial.